# SSRS External image expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder

We are using External image source for dynamic client logo. Using `=Code.Portal.GetClientLogo(Lookup(Parameters!P_CLIENT_KEY.Value, Fields!Client_Key.Value, Fields!Client_Name.Value, "Clients"))` expression for client logo. I don't seem to find `Code.Portal.GetClientLogo` function in reports properties.Please suggest. We are using SSRS 2008R2 Report Builder.

I appreciate your help.

Thank You!

Comment: Is your image stored in a DB?

Comment: In the Report Properties, look in the References tab. That looks like an assembly reference.

Comment: Under reference tab i see class name as EIR.Reporting.AddIns.Portal and instance name as portal. I don't find Code.Portal.GetClientLogo.  // @StevenWhite

Comment: My Images are stored on SSRS Server. @newGuy

Comment: Do you mean the custom report code does not contain a function called Portal.GetClientLogo or are you asking where to look to find the custom code?

Comment: Yes,Custom report does not contain fuction called Portal.GetClientLogo @RossBush. I looked for it all over in the rdl file but no luck. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Was that report copied from another report. If you copied some of the report items you need to make sure you go back to the source report and grab the custom code as well.